# Prevent divs from disappearing as long as the user has the mouse on another div

Tags: jquery

The following code makes `.fixed-toolbar`, `.fixed-submit`, and `.fixed-toggle` appear and disappear when the user places the cursor on `.fixed-toolbar`:

```
 $(document).on("mouseover", ".fixed-container", function(){
    $('.fullscreen .fixed-toolbar').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $(".fullscreen .fixed-submit").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $(".fullscreen .fixed-toggle .exit-fullscreen").css('visibility', 'visible');
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      $(".fullscreen .fixed-toolbar").css('visibility', 'hidden');
      $(".fullscreen .fixed-submit").css('visibility', 'hidden');
      $(".fullscreen .fixed-toggle .exit-fullscreen").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }, 3000 ); 
  });
```

The divs disappear 3 seconds after even if the user keeps the mouse on the `.fixed-toolbar`. I would like to prevent the divs from disappearing as long as the user has the mouse on `.fixed-toolbar` (and only make it disappear 3 seconds after the cursor leaves `.fixed-toolbar`).

How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".fixed-container", function(){
    $('.fullscreen .fixed-toolbar, .fullscreen .fixed-submit, .fullscreen .fixed-toggle .exit-fullscreen').fadeIn();
}).on('mouseleave', '.fixed-container', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.fullscreen .fixed-toolbar, .fullscreen .fixed-submit, .fullscreen .fixed-toggle .exit-fullscreen').fadeOut();
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Strange, the div still disappears after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".fixed-container", function(){
    $('.fullscreen .fixed-toolbar, .fullscreen .fixed-submit, .fullscreen .fixed-toggle .exit-fullscreen').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
$(document).on("mouseout",".fixed-container",function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    $(".fullscreen .fixed-toolbar, .fullscreen .fixed-submit, .fullscreen .fixed-toggle .exit-fullscreen").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    },3000);
});
```

OR, if you use `display:none;` instead of `visibility:hidden;` in your css:

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".fixed-container", function(){
    $(".fixed-toolbar, .fixed-submit, .exit-fullscreen").show();
});
$(document).on("mouseout",".fixed-container",function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".fixed-toolbar, .fixed-submit, .exit-fullscreen").hide();
    },1000);
});
```

OR go for some built-in jQuery effects:

```
$(document).on("mouseover", ".fixed-container", function(){
    $(".fixed-toolbar, .fixed-submit, .exit-fullscreen").slideDown();
});
$(document).on("mouseout",".fixed-container",function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".fixed-toolbar, .fixed-submit, .exit-fullscreen").slideUp();
    },1000);
});
```